# Unable to connect to ftp: (407) Proxy Authentication Required

Tags: c#, .net, ftp

I need to connect to an ftp and download a file from it, but I'm unable to connect to it. I've specified the credentials and am able to connect through my browser, but not through .NET.

```
        FtpWebRequest downloadRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ftpSite + "/" + TOC);
        downloadRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
        downloadRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, pass);
        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)downloadRequest.GetResponse(); //execption thrown here
        Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);

        reader.ReadLine();

        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            data.Add(reader.ReadLine());

        reader.Close();
```

It throws a `WebException` with the 407 error and I'm not quite sure why.  My boss is baffled as well.  Any insight?

Comment: This [post][1] may help


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524566/407-proxy-authentication-required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you are sitting behind an FTP proxy that requires authentication.

Try initializing

```
downloadRequest.Proxy
```

with appropriate proxy credentials, e.g. something like

```
WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy("http://proxy:80/", true); 
proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("userId", "password", "Domain"); 
downloadRequest.Proxy = proxy;
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use the command-line FTP client to do it?

I expect that the error message you got already explains the problem - you're behind an application-level firewall which requires you to authenticate using the proxy.   Your browser is presumably already configured to do this.   Consult your network administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Putting a `<defaultProxy />` element into in app.config / web.config under `<system.net>` with `useDefaultCredentials="true"` may well help. Depending on your network setup, this may avoid you needing to hard code proxy account details in your app.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" />
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```