# The Code return error A column named 'link' already belongs

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xml

```
 public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.ReadXml(@"http://tecnologia.ig.com.br/rss.xml");

            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            XmlUrlResolver resolver = new XmlUrlResolver();
            resolver.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("bruno", "*****");//intentionally hiding real password from stackoverflow
            doc.XmlResolver = resolver;

            foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables["item"].Rows)
            {
                Response.Write("Item TITLE: " + dr["title"].ToString() + "<br />");
                Response.Write("Descrição : " + dr["description"].ToString() + "<br />");
                Response.Write("Data de Publicação: " + dr["pubDate"].ToString() + "<br />");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

I execute the Code, and the system return two error's
  1 -  A column named 'link' already belongs to this DataTable: cannot set a nested table name to the same name.
  2 - The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required.

Thanks!

Comment: Likely the first error relates to the second.
Take a look here for some info about your settings which may remove the second error, and hopefully the first:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524566/407-proxy-authentication-required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just provide an idea for reading RSS Feed:

1. Create a WebRequest and WebReponse object:

   ```
   WebRequest request=WebRequest.Create("your url");
   WebReponse response=request.GetRespose();
   ```
2. Create a XML document and load the XML document with stream from response object:

   ```
   Stream rssStream=response.GetResponseStream();
   XMLDocument xmlDoc=new XMLDocument();
   xmlDoc.Load(rssStream);
   ```
3. Retrieve matching XML nodes from XMLDocument with XMLNodeList:

   ```
   XmlNodeList xmlNodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("your XPath expression");
   ```
4. Now you can loop  the RSS feed items to get what you want:

   ```
    for (int i = 0; i < xmlNodeList.Count; i++)
       {
           XmlNode xmlNode;

           xmlNode = xmlNodeList.Item(i).SelectSingleNode("ProductName");
           //xmlNode.InnerText;
       }
   ```

Comment: This is the kind of suggestion I'd go with, rather than parsing it into a dataset

Comment: System.Net.WebProxy proxy = new System.Net.WebProxy(@"ip:door");
    proxy.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("User", "Pass");
    System.Net.WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = proxy;

I solved the problem 1... and the problem number two it is related to the rss web site (rss/XML corrupted) I just changed the link and it worked, thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd problem:

You probably have a corporate proxy, try using this in the web.config:

```
<system.net>
  <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" />
</system.net>
```

As for the 1st problem:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1220157.aspx/1

The issue is likely because XML will allow duplicate nodes and a data table will not allow duplicate columns, so you cannot parse directly to a data table.

I would suggest doing some research into parsing and using XML data before going to far down the data table route